# HTML Email In Outlook Background Image

Tags: html, email, html-email

I am making a HTML email with a background image. Right now, I can not get the background image to show in outlook. I tried the "Bulletproof background images" from http://backgrounds.cm/ but haven't had success yet.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background: url(https://raw2.github.com/dman777/icons/master/full_size.png);">
    <table class="body" style="background: url(https://raw2.github.com/dman777/icons/master/full_size.png)">
        <div style="background-color:#7bceeb;">
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
        <v:fill type="tile" src="https://raw2.github.com/dman777/icons/master/full_size.png" color="#7bceeb"/>
        </v:background>
        <![endif]-->
        <table height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="left" background="https://raw2.github.com/dman777/icons/master/full_size.png">
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>

    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change the `https://github.com/dman777/icons/blob/master/full_size.png` to `https://github.com/dman777/icons/blob/master/full_size.png` as the first link isn't to a picture.

Comment: Sorry, I just now fixed that but still no success.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is adding quotes around the image in the url().

Comment: Have you tried using an image from an `http` protocol URL instead of `https`? It could be a protocol error or mismatch (but that's just a guess)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280715/full-width-backgrounds-on-outlook-07-10-13

Answer (score 2):

You are missing your closing conditionals after your table:

```
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
```

Check [backgrounds.cm](http://backgrounds.cm/) again for full example.

Comment: Not sure what you mean...they are there right after <div style="background-color:#7bceeb;">

Comment: Sorry - thought you were doing the background on a table/element, not the whole document. Take a look at that option on backgrounds.cm - it may offer you a solution if you apply it to the body wrapper table.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook/Outlook.com do not support background images.

*Source: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/*

Comment: indeed, but the bullet proof method from http://backgrounds.cm/  is supposed to allow it.

Comment: Outlook also supports background images in the body tag.